# React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Is there another way to do this without having to place the useState variables outside the map function?

```js
const slimy = [];
{
  slimy.map(function (item) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState("");

    return (
      <ListItem
        key={item.createdAt}
        style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <div>
          <p>{count}</p>

          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
        </div>
      </ListItem>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, just make the jsx that's inside the map into another component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom component.

```
{
  slimy.map(function (item) {
    return (
      <CustomItem key={item.createdAt} names={item.names} />
    );
  });
}
```

```
const CustomItem = (props) => {
   console.log(props.names);  // <----------------
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   return (
     <ListItem style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
       <div>
         <p>{count}</p>
         <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} />
       </div>
     </ListItem>
   )
}
```

Comment: so, how can i use the items from the list in the seperate component?

Comment: for example, the list contains names, where will i render the list of names?

Comment: just like the ```item.createdAt```, where will i use the ```item.names``` ?

Comment: will you tick & upvote if it is correct answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226420/discussion-between-prime-and-raphael-inyang).

Comment: yes, surely i will, if i try it and it works

Answer (score 2):

You can put an array into state instead:

```
const [countArr, setCountArr] = useState(
  () => new Array(slimy.length).fill(0)
);
return slimy.map(function(item, i){
  <ListItem key={item.createdAt} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <div>
      <p>{countArr[i]}</p>
      <button onClick={() => { setCountArr(
        countArr.map((count, j) => i === j ? count + 1 : count)
      ) }} />
      </div>
  </ListItem>)
});
```